# Error on account activation django_registration_email

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I've implemented authentication on my application using django_registration and django_registration email. Here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',

#custom apps
'order',
'fiesta',

#3rd party apps
'south',
'jquery',
'djangoformsetjs',

# DEVELOPER TOOLS
'debug_toolbar',
#authentication apps
'registration',
'registration_email',
```

)

```
#DJANGO REGISTRATION SETTINGS

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # one week activation window

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'registration_email.auth.EmailBackend',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', lambda x:HttpResponseRedirect("/fiesta/workspace/"), name="home"),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration_email.backends.default.urls')),
url(r'^fiesta/', include('fiesta.urls')),
```

)

The registration email is sent okay but when i click on the account activation link, here is the error i get:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/blaqx/.virtualenv/django5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
115.response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/blaqx/.virtualenv/django5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
68.return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blaqx/.virtualenv/django5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
86.return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blaqx/.virtualenv/django5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in get
126.success_url = self.get_success_url(request, activated_user)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/activate/bf93e2619ad0b7419b34dc0284e172fae8ecafef/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

In the error, I can see that during account activation, a reference is being made to django-registration instead of django-registration-email. I however don't know if this is the cause of the error and how to solve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say: account activation link, where is that pointed in the link in you urls.py and the view for that link?

Comment: LearningNeverStops, url(r'^accounts/', include('registration_email.backends.default.urls')) maps the registration urls to their respective views. View django_registration_email setup instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are using two packages for same purpose(i.e; sending the email activation), Here the packeges,

1. django-registration-email
2. django-registration

Select the one package from above. I choose django-registration, Here the doc https://django-registration.readthedocs.org.

And follow the code instructions,

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',

#custom apps
'order',
'fiesta',

#3rd party apps
'south',
'jquery',
'djangoformsetjs',

# DEVELOPER TOOLS
'debug_toolbar',
#authentication apps
'registration',
#'registration_email',
)

#DJANGO REGISTRATION SETTINGS

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # one week activation window

#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
#'registration_email.auth.EmailBackend',
#)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', lambda x:HttpResponseRedirect("/fiesta/workspace/"), name="home"),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
url(r'^fiesta/', include('fiesta.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Dhana, in the applicaton, I intended to use django-registration-email, so that email is used as the unique field for sign up. Please see https://github.com/bitmazk/django-registration-email. I have used it several times before with the above setup but I don't know where the error came from this time.